# Does Earth geography resemble anything metaphorical?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, science

All I know about the traditional geographical metaphorism is that Jerusalem is the center of the world and the whole inhabitable space is divided between the 70 nations (besides the plain facts, like a sea here and a valley there).

What additional geographical phenomena have metaphorical meaning in Judaism, e.g. the form if Eretz Israel, the number and form of continents, the shape of the oceans, the topology of the Earth, from the Dead Sea to Everest, the paths of the rivers, etc?

Comment: Italy represents "boots"

Comment: The three sections of the Temple, the (mostly)concentric courts surrounding it, the Temple grounds, the areas around it, Jerusalem, the Land of Israel and the surrounding nations' territories have all been food for metaphoric thoughts over the years. The DSS folks in some of their main documents had  the "translation" of "camp" being Jerusalem, and a lot of Tanach words were allegedly 'decoded"(very seriously!) by them to suit their worldview.

Comment: More "botanical" than geographic - see the numerous references in Yehayahu and Tehillim among other places that discuss trees waving, clapping their hands, etc.